# onload not working in <img> element

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why this function doesn't fire. I want to declare an image in HTML with a single `onload` function, which will automatically take care of the image's source and `mouseover/out` functions.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<img id="menuBtnNovo" onload="imgButton(this)"/>
```

and the JS function `imgButton` looks like this:

```
function imgButton(e){
    window.alert("asdasdad");
    e.src="images/def/" + e.Id + ".png";
    e.onmouseover= function(){ *change image here*}
    e.onmouseout= function(){ *change image back here*}
}
```

Now, not even the alert pops up, and I don't know why. I tried putting script in `<head>` and setting `src` to none `src=""` in the `<img>`. I'm using Firefox, but it doesn't work in Edge either.

**Question is:** how do I fire `onload` function on an image element?

Also, if you have any idea of your own way of implementing this behaviour of automatically loading certain images (that would actually be buttons/links), feel free to share it. I'm new to JS but not to programming.

As you might see, all images are in `"images/def/..."` and all images for when the mouse is over the `img` are in `"images/mo/..."`.

Comment: onload is fired when image is loaded and for this you need src attribute with valid image.

Comment: so maybe if I did the same, but with div and background-image property?

Comment: A div does not support the onload event, so no.

Comment: You could just go for a window.onload event to create the images on the page and use css to do the hovering repalcement.

Comment: Why not just do this after the DOM loads, and search for all images without a `src`? `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("img:not([src])"), imgButton)`

Comment: I'm trying to achieve short, self-explanatory HTML button. more on point: to write <element_name id="nameOfTheButton" onload="LoadAsButton(this)"> and I want the LoadAsButton function to set everything automaticly and the element's ID would be the parameter for images to take.

Comment: You might call it self-explanatory but it is not suggested to mix your layout, code and interactions so deeply. Look into `addEventListenener` instead of this to separate your code from your layout and markup. The same goes for the `.onmouseover` - try using `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always try and let browser do image replacements, but if you have to use script, than you can do something like this on [DOM ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), or [window load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event:

```js
$('img[data-regular]').each(function(i) {
    var thisImage = $(this);
    var regular = thisImage.data('regular');
    var hover = thisImage.data('hover');
    thisImage.attr('src', regular);
    /* Preload image for hover */
    $('<img/>')[0].src = hover;
    /* Set events */
    thisImage.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        thisImage.attr('src', hover);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        thisImage.attr('src', regular);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-regular="https://placehold.it/350x150" data-hover="https://placehold.it/450x200" />
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt8gt9v0/).

Comment: You might want to mention that this is jQuery and not pure Javascript. (Well, _uses_ JQuery - this would be easy in regular javascript it makes me wonder why people still flock to jQuery)

Comment: Short and simple. Thanks :D I do have to look a bit more into JQ, but this is awesome! thanks!

Comment: @somethinghere, I am glad you are young enough and have no clue how it was 13 years ago dealing with ugly browsers. jQuery made a revolution in 2006 and many of frustrated developers felt such a relief. Firebug was released just after it and both changed our lives. If I can do something easy way, why would I try and do it harder? At the end, it is the question of choice, some people still like to type into console... but no, not me, not in 21st century.

Comment: @skobaljic I have used jQuery, but times have changed and pure javascript is more advanced and universal. It is now awesome, and jQuery feels like a heavt library, certainly if people use about four methods of it. But thats just my take :)

Comment: Think I would die if I had to serialize form data and send ajax post request to get json in pure Javascript, than to handle errors. Would be much better if jQuery is delivered and included with every browser update - it is used on [96% of websites that use frameworks, and 70.8% of all the websites](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all).